# Associative Array symfony2 console

Tags: php, symfony

given this configuration command:

```
protected function configure() {
    $this->setName('command:test')
         ->addOption("service", null, InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY | InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, "What services are desired ?", array(
             "s1" => true,
             "s2" => true,
             "s3" => true,
             "s4" => false,
             "s5" => true,
             "s6" => true,
             "s7" => true,
             "s8" => true,
             "s9" => true
         ))
}
```

Now when calling the command, how do you pass the associate array.

```
#!/bin/bash
php app/console command:test --service s1:true --service s2:false --s3:true
```

Condition:

- I dont want to create 9+ options for this command.
- Ideally, I would like to preserve the defaults when I pass a new service.
- All, within the command definition if that's possible. That is no supporting code. No `if`

Answer (score 4):

As far I know it's not possible when using **Command Options** (at least not like you've described...).

The best workaround (IMO) is using **Command Arguments** (instead of *Command Options*) and writing extra code (not, it is not nice to put all of extra code inside command definition although is possible).

It would be something like this:

```
class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function getDefaultServicesSettings()
    {
        return [
            's1' => true,
            's2' => true,
            's3' => true,
            's4' => false,
            's5' => true,
            's6' => true,
            's7' => true,
            's8' => true,
            's9' => true
        ];
    }

    private function normalizeServicesValues($values)
    {
        if (!$values) {
            return $this->getDefaultServicesSettings();
        }

        $new = [];

        foreach ($values as $item) {
            list($service, $value) = explode(':', $item);
            $new[$service] = $value == 'true' ? true : false;
        }
        return array_merge($this->getDefaultServicesSettings(), $new);
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('commant:test')
            ->addArgument(
                'services',
                InputArgument::IS_ARRAY|InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'What services are desired ?');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $services = $this->normalizeServicesValues(
            $input->getArgument('services'));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then

```
$ bin/console commant:test s1:false s9:false
```

That overwrites s1 and s2 values while keeping defaults.